# AngularJS Scope Variables not Updating

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Strange error here. I have this form:

```
<form name="newaccount" id="newaccount" ng-submit="doSubmit()">
<label>username</label>
<input name="username" type="text" required ng-model="username">
<span ui-toggle="username.length > 15">Too long!</span>
<label>name</label>
<input name="name" type="text" required ng-model="name">
<label>e-mail</label>
<input name="email" type="email" required ng-model="email" ui-validate>
<label>password</label>
<input name="password" type="password" required ng-model="password" ui-validate>
<div style="text-align: center;"><br>
<input type="submit"></div>
</form>
```

And this controller:

```
$scope.username = "f";
$scope.password = "f";
$scope.email = "f";
$scope.name = "f";
$scope.doSubmit = function(){
    //Transition to progress view
    $scope.showLoginForm = false;
    $scope.showCreateForm = false;
    $scope.showLoading = true;
    $scope.resultSuccess = false;
    $scope.showResult = false;
    $scope.loadingMessage = "Creating account...";
    $scope.resultReason = "Success!";

    //Send POST
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "php/createaccount.php",
        data: {
            "username": $scope.username,
            "password": $scope.password,
            "name": $scope.name,
            "email": $scope.email
        }}
    ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.showLoading = false;
            $scope.showResult = true;
            $scope.resultSuccess = data === "success";
            if($scope.resultSuccess){
                $scope.resultReason = "Account created successfully!";
            }else{
                $scope.resultReason = data;
            }

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.showLoading = false;
            $scope.showResult = true;
            $scope.resultSuccess = false;
            $scope.resultReason = data;
        });
};
```

As expected, "f" appears in each of the fields. However, if you change these fields and then submit the form, the server responds (with a print_r() on the post data) showing that the JSON received by the backend ALWAYS will contain "f" as the value for each of the fields, not the changed values.

Example:
with username "test" etc.

```
{"username":"f","password":"f","name":"f","email":"f"}
```

Therefore, the values in $scope aren't getting updated for some reason when I type in the forms. What gives?

Comment: is it possible that the code that assigns "f" to the fields runs every time the form is submitted?

Comment: perhaps, if I removed that part though nothing is submitted! (literally, no keys or values)

Comment: would you be able to set up this code on jsfiddle ? do not have to send the POST, just output to console.

Comment: Instead of assigning individual $scope properties inside the $http call, consider using a "large object" on your scope:  $scope.person = { username: 'f', ...}.  Then you can just post that object.  See [Dean's blog](http://deansofer.com/posts/view/14/AngularJs-Tips-and-Tricks-UPDATED#serialize).

Comment: Mark please submit that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Mark you still have not submitted this as an answer :D I want to accept this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning individual $scope properties inside the $http call, use a "large object" on your scope: $scope.person = { username: 'f', ...}. Then you can just post that object.

It turned out the specific problem in this was that angular does not write values to scope variables unless they validate, in this case email wasn't validating properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is the scope clearly defined using 'ng-app' and 'ng-controller'?

I could not find these two directives in your html. Perhaps you didnt include it as part of question.

A sample structure which i expected: http://angularjs.org/#todo-html

Comment: The code you see here is within a ng-view, within a ng-app directive. The controller is defined in app.js. I can confirm the controller is working because the methods in the controller are being called.